# python property decorator for __name__ attr in class

Tags: python

I find a good desc for python property in this link
[How does the @property decorator work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work-in-python)
below example shows how it works, while I find an exception for class attr '**name**'
now I have a reload function which will raise an error

```
@property
def foo(self): return self._foo
really means the same thing as

def foo(self): return self._foo
foo = property(foo)
```

here is my example

```
class A(object):
@property
def __name__(self):
    return 'dd'
    
a = A()
print(a.__name__)
```

dd
this works, however below cannot work

```
class B(object):
    pass

def test(self):
    return 'test'

B.t = property(test)
print(B.t)
B.__name__ = property(test)
```

> 

```
<property object at 0x7f71dc5e1180>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 23, in <module>
TypeError: can only assign string to B.__name__, not 'property'
```

Does anyone knows the difference for builtin **name** attr, it works if I use normal property decorator, while not works for the 2nd way. now I have a requirement to reload the function when code changes, however this error will block the reload procedure. Can anyone helps? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: `__name__` is deep magic in CPython.

So, first, let's get the technicalities out of the way. To quote what you said

> ```
> @property
> def foo(self): return self._foo
> really means the same thing as
>
> def foo(self): return self._foo
> foo = property(foo)
> ```

This is correct. But it can be a bit misleading. You have this `A` class

```
class A(object):
  @property
  def __name__(self):
    return 'dd'
```

And you claim that it's equivalent to this `B` class

```
class B(object):
  pass

def test(self):
  return 'test'

B.__name__ = property(test)
```

which is not correct. It's actually equivalent to this

```
def test(self):
  return 'test'

class B(object):
  __name__ = property(test)
```

which works and does what you expect it to. And you're also correct that, for most names in Python, your `B` and my `B` would be the same. What difference does it make whether I'm assigning to a name inside the class or immediately after its declaration? Replace `__name__` with `ravioli` in the above snippets and either will work. So what makes `__name__` special?

That's where the magic comes in. When you define a name *inside* the class, you're working *directly* on the class' internal dictionary, so

```
class A:
  foo = 1

  def bar(self):
    return 1
```

This defines two things on the *class* `A`. One happens to be a number and the other happens to be a function (which will likely be called as a bound method). Now we can access these.

```
A.foo # Returns 1, simple access
A.bar # Returns the function object bar
A().foo # Returns 1
A().bar # Returns a bound method object
```

When we look up the names directly on `A`, we simply access the slots like we would on any object. However, when we look them up on `A()` (an instance of `A`), a multi-step process happens

1. Look up the name on the instance's `__dict__` directly.
2. If that failed, then look up the name on the class' `__dict__`.
3. If we found it on the class, see if there's a `__get__` on the result and call it.

That third step is what allows bound method objects to work, and it's also the mechanism underlying the `property` decorators in Python.

Let's go through this whole process with a property called `ravioli`. No magic here.

```
class A(object):
  @property
  def ravioli(self):
    return 'dd'
```

When we do `A().ravioli`, first we see if there's a `ravioli` on the instance we just made. There isn't, so we check the class' `__dict__`, and indeed we find a `property` object at that position. That `property` object has a `__get__`, so we call it, and it returns `'dd'`, so indeed we get the string `'dd'`.

```
>>> A().ravioli
'dd'
```

Now I would expect that, if I do `A.ravioli`, we will simply get the `property` object. Since we're not calling it on an *instance*, we don't call `__get__`.

```
>>> A.ravioli
<property object at 0x7f5bd3690770>
```

And indeed, we get the property object, as expected.

Now let's do the *exact* same thing but replace `ravioli` with `__name__`.

```
class A(object):
  @property
  def __name__(self):
    return 'dd'
```

Great! Now let's make an instance.

```
>>> A().__name__
'dd'
```

Sensible, we looked up `__name__` on `A`'s `__dict__` and found a property, so we called its `__get__`. Nothing weird.

Now

```
>>> A.__name__
'A'
```

Um... what? If we had just found the property on `A`'s `__dict__`, then we should see that property here, right?

Well, no, not always. See, in the abstract, `foo.bar` normally looks in `foo.__dict__` for a field called `bar`. But it doesn't do that if the *type* of `foo` defines a `__getattribute__`. If it defines that, then that method is *always* called instead.

Now, the type of `A` is `type`, the type of all Python types. Read that sentence a few times and make sure it makes sense. And if we do a bit of spelunking into the CPython source code, we see that [`type` actually defines `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/typeobject.c#L1014) for the following names:

- `__name__`
- `__qualname__`
- `__bases__`
- `__module__`
- `__abstractmethods__`
- `__dict__`
- `__doc__`
- `__text_signature__`
- `__annotations__`

That explains how `__name__` can serve double duty as a property on the class instances and also as an accessible field on the same class. It also explains why you get that highly specialized error message when reassigning to `B.__name__`: the line

```
B.__name__ = property(test)
```

is actually equivalent to

```
type.__setattr__(B, '__name__', property(test))
```

which is calling our special-case checker in CPython.

For any other type in Python, in particular for user-defined types, we could get around this with `object.__setattr__`. Unfortunately,

```
>>> object.__setattr__(B, '__name__', property(test))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't apply this __setattr__ to type object
```

[There's a really specific check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/typeobject.c#L6866) to make sure we don't do exactly this, and the comment reads

> ```
> /* Reject calls that jump over intermediate C-level overrides. */
> ```

We also can't use metaclasses to override `__setattr__` and `__getattribute__`, because the instance lookup procedure specifically doesn't call those (in the above examples, `__getattribute__` was called in every case *except* the one we care about for `property` purposes). I even tried subclassing `str` to trick `__setattr__` into accepting our made-up value

```
class NameProperty(str):

    def __new__(cls, value, **kwargs):
        return str.__new__(cls, value)

    def __init__(self, value, method):
        self.method = method

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.method(instance)

B.__name__ = NameProperty(B.__name__, method=test)
```

This actually passes the `__setattr__` check, but it doesn't assign to `B.__dict__` (since the `__setattr__` still assigns to the actual CPython-level name, not to `B.__dict__['__name__']`), so the property lookup doesn't work.

So... that's how I reached my conclusion of: `__name__` is deep magic in CPython. All of the usual Python metaprogramming techniques have failed, and all of the methods getting called are written deep down in C. My advice to you is: Stop using `__name__` for things it's not intended for, or be prepared to write some C code and hack on CPython directly.

Comment: "we see that `type` actually defines `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__` for the following names" - that's not what's going on there. That `type_getsets` array gets processed to generate a bunch of descriptors for the listed names, much like how `property` works. It's not defining any special-case handling directly in `__getattribute__` or `__setattr__`.

Comment: You can see the code that generates those descriptors in [`type_add_getset`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.3/Objects/typeobject.c#L5655), which is a helper function for `PyType_Ready`,